# Como saber se uma consulta retornou verdadeiro

Tags: php

Estou fazendo o cadastro de usuários no sistema, porém não consigo saber o resultado da minha query no banco já tentei até retornar o valor do execute porém não tive sucesso, alguma solução?

Obs: Eu já estou conseguindo inserir os dados no banco

**Meu código do banco**

```
<?php 

    class Banco{

        private $conexao, $usuario;

        public function __construct(Conexao $conexao, Usuario $usuario){
            $this->conexao = $conexao->conectar();
            $this->usuario = $usuario;
        }
        public function inserir(){
            $query = 'insert into usuario(idUsuario, email, senha, nome) values(?, ?, ?, ?)';   
            $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$this->usuario->__get('idUsuario'));
            $stmt->bindValue(2,$this->usuario->__get('email'));
            $stmt->bindValue(3,$this->usuario->__get('senha'));
            $stmt->bindValue(4,$this->usuario->__get('nome'));
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        public function excluir(){

        }

        public function recuperarRegistros(){

        }

        public function pesquisarUsuario($id){
            $query = 'select idUsuario from usuario where id = ?';
            $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$this->usuario->__get('idUsuario'));
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }


    ?>
```

**Pagina que chama a operação**

```
<?php 
 require_once '../../projetoPrivado/Banco.php';
require_once '../../projetoPrivado/Conexao.php';
require_once '../../projetoPrivado/Usuario.php';

echo'<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$conexao = new Conexao();
$usuario = new Usuario($_POST['nome'],$_POST['senha'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['id']);
$banco = new Banco($conexao, $usuario);
echo'<pre>';
    print_r($usuario);
echo '</pre>';
// $banco->inserir();

 $banco->pesquisarUsuario($_POST['id']);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá fiz uma modificação na função `pesquisarUsuario()`, não sei se vai dar certo, mas faça um teste ai e poste para nós o resultado...

```
public function pesquisarUsuario($id){
            $query = 'select idUsuario from usuario where id = ?';
            $stmt = $this->conexao->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$this->usuario->__get('idUsuario'));
            $stmt->execute();
            $fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($fetch)>0)
              return $fetch;
            else 
              return 'nenhum resultado encontrado';
        }
```

Comment: Apesar de eu achar válido a sua resposta, a pergunta diz.. "Como saber se a consulta retornou verdadeiro" ... O que seria apenas `return $stmt->execute();`... Mas acho que é isso na sua resposta que ele pretende mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado lodi, era isso mesmo